# Import Module error in Python Using Mercury

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, module

Would like some clarification on the following.

My folder structure is below:

[image]

It is running OK on VS Code
[image]

But when running on Mercury i have some module import errors
[image]

Please help.
Thanks.